# Ionic 3 Lazy loading plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, lazy-loading, ionic3

So with Ionic 3 lazy loading of pages and components was introduced into the framework. I have app optimized to lazy load all the pages now but it still has a slow startup time. I do however use a lot of native plugins which I think might be the reason for this slow start up.

Now in Ionic the native plugins are wrapped in Angular, so would it be possible to also lazy load the plugins so that the plugins, which might only come into play at certain moments of app usage, won't get loaded until necessary hence improving boot performance?

Comment: What command do you use when deploying to your device? Make sure to use the `--prod` flag, to ensure that your web content will be minified. `ionic run android --prod`  This will improve  your startup time.

Comment: Are you using ionic native v 3+?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you could remove the native plugins from your main app.module.ts and add it to the component's module that's actually using the plugin. That way the plugin will only be called when the module it's loaded.

Comment: This worked for me but maybe good idea to mention that you should add a providers array in your pages module (where you will use the plugin) and insert the plugin name there (as opposed to adding it to imports). e.g in my HomePage module. import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
  providers: [
    File
  ],...

Comment: By importing specific page, it is working but I seen it get load when first time app start.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to add any plugin for lazy loading.
Go to your **app.componer.ts** file just change **rootPage:any = HomePage;** to **rootPage:string = "HomePage";**.
You don't need import your file.